# Web Administration Tool: Unable to connect to SQL Server database on another computer

Tags: asp.net, database

I am currently using MS Visual Web developer 2010 Express to build a website as a school project. I used the Website Administration Tool and set up my login and registration form and everything. Everything works perfectly at home when I run the website, I can login and I can use the registration form to create a new user. Today I took it to school on my flash drive to show my teacher. Using her laptop I opened my website using MS Visual Web developer 2010 Express. Now when I try to register a new user or login with the users I already created at home, I get an error page with a long list of codes. So, I immediately went to the Website Administration Tool to check what is going on. I clicked the Security tab and I got this message:

> There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid >server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the >role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page >where you can choose a new data store.
>
> The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Unable to connect to SQL Server database.

I am confused now. Why won't it work on another computer? Is this feature meant to work only on the computer you created it with?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like configuration issue to me. What do you use as a datasource (mdf/mdb file or a database instance of SQL server?

Comment: My App_Data folder has a mdf file. ASPNETDB.MDF

Comment: what connection string do you use access it? try to change from windows authentication to user, it will work then.

Comment: I cannot find any connection string settings in my web.config files.

Comment: did you look at my suggested answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to deploy your mdf file to remote server.
Here you are the steps: [Deploying the ASPNETDB.MDF to a Remote SQL Server Database](http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/archive/2008/11/04/deploying-the-aspnetdb-mdf-to-a-production-server.aspx)